# Parsing Google Search API XML results via iOS Objective-C 2.0

Tags: objective-c, xml, ios, nsxmlparser, google-api

Here are the XML results from my Google API request:

```
<entry gd:kind="shopping#product">
<author>
<name>Bloomingdale&apos;s</name>
</author>
<title>7 For All Mankind &quot;Ginger&quot; Wide Leg Jeans in Lightweight Mercer Wash</title>
<s:product>
<s:author>
<s:name>Bloomingdale&apos;s</s:name>
<s:accountId>8020</s:accountId>
</s:author>
<s:title>7 For All Mankind &quot;Ginger&quot; Wide Leg Jeans in Lightweight Mercer Wash</s:title>
<s:description>7 for all Mankind &quot;Ginger&quot; jeans in lightweight mercer wash. A wide-leg fit.</s:description>
<s:brand>7 For All Mankind</s:brand>
<s:gtin>12345680753539</s:gtin>
<s:images>
<s:image link="http://images.bloomingdales.com/is/image/BLM/products/2/optimized/1144762_fpx.tif?wid=287&amp;qlt=90"/>
<s:image link="http://1.0.0.0/"/>
<s:image link="http://0.0.0.5/"/>
</s:images>
</s:product>
</entry>
```

Here is my NSXMLParser code to parse the XML:

@implementation ItemViewController

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser  
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName  
namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI  
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName  
attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{  
if ([elementName isEqual:@"s:product"]) {  
    NSLog(@"found Product!");
    if (!"s:product")
        productScanned = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return;
}

if ([elementName isEqual:@"s:gtin"]) {
    // set ItemNumber as the GTIN of the productScanned     
    itemNumber = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
}

if ([elementName isEqual:@"s:title"]) {
    // set ItemDesc as the item description of the productScanned
    itemDesc = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
}

if ([elementName isEqual:@"s:brand"]) {
    // set ItemBrand as the brand description of the productScanned
    itemBrand = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
}

if ([elementName isEqual:@"s:name"]) {
    // set ItemStore as the store location of the productScanned
    itemStore = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
}

// Create array of Image Tags
if ([elementName isEqual:@"s:images"]) {
    NSLog(@"found Images!");
    if (!itemImageURLArray)
        itemImageURLArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return; 

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"s:image"]) {
        // itemImagesArray is an NSMutableArray instance variable
        if (!itemImagesArray)
            itemImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSString *thisLink = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"link"];
        if (thisLink)
            // do something
        return;
    }
}
itemImageURL = [itemImagesArray objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Why do my results return all element information except for the `<s:images>` and `<s:image>` elements?

Better yet.  Help me understand why my array for parsing `<s:images>` isn't loading those elements into my `*itemImageURL` pointer?

Comment: What does the line `if (!"s:images")` mean?

Comment: Typo in code... has been replaced with `if (!itemImageURLArray)`
Thx for catching that, Anna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `itemImageURLArray` is supposed to contain the url strings and `itemImagesArray` the actual images the urls point to.

The `s:image` elements are never processed because that code is inside the `if` block for `s:images`.  When `didStartElement` is called for `s:image`, that code never runs.  Move it outside  the `if` for `s:images`.

Also, in the code that handles `s:image`, you probably want to add the url string to the `itemImageURLArray` array.  After the line that sets `thisLink`, try adding:

```
[itemImageURLArray addObject:thisLink];
```

As for downloading the images themselves into `itemImagesArray`, I would do it as a separate step after the xml parsing.  You can loop through the `itemImagesArray` and download the images asynchronously.

By the way, this line:

```
if (!"s:product")
```

should probably be:

```
if (!productScanned)
```